# 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1330: character maps to <undefined> while loading ontology

Tags: character-encoding

I am trying to load an ontology from local file. But while loading the ontology I am facing this issue.
[image]

Kindly look into it.
Thaks a lot.

`from owlready import * onto = get_ontology("file://qa.ontology.v1.owl").load()`

I have come to know that this issue arises due to the different encoding type. And this issue will be resolved if we write `encoding = "utf-8"`. But i dont know where to write it.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Here is the way to load the ontology with its relevant encoding.

***onto = get_ontology("file://qa.ontology.v1.owl").load(fileobj=open("qa.ontology.v1.owl", "r", encoding="utf-8"))***